# lein ring uberwar command NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, clojure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, leiningen

I'm having a hard time get a war generated using eclipse.

First, I'm trying to deploy a clojure app to AWS via Elastic Beanstalk. I'm open to suggestions on how to do this (ie via lien beanstalk) but I wanted to keep it simple and create a war then upload/deploy to elastic beanstalk (on the tomcat platform). Currently the Elastic Beanstalk sample app is running.

I'm using windowsx64, Eclipse Luna and Jre8 with counterclockwise 0.27.1

I created the project using eclipse and the compojure leinengen template. Here is the project clj file:

```
(defproject aws-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.8"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.11"]]
  :ring {:handler aws-test.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

Here is the code in handler.clj file:

```
(ns aws-test.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

I can load this in a REPL successfully but when I right click on the project and open a generic leinengen command line, then execute "lein ring uberwar" either nothing happens or I get some variation of the following dumped in the console window:

```
Compiling aws-test.handler
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ring/middleware/file_info$loading__4958__auto__, compiling:(route.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3558)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7226)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at aws_test.handler$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(handler.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3553)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7226)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)
    at user$eval15.invoke(form-init3989860914484838550.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ring/middleware/file_info$loading__4958__auto__
    at ring.middleware.file_info__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at ring.middleware.file_info__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5618)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at compojure.route$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(route.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3553)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ring.middleware.file_info$loading__4958__auto__
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 75 more
```

I even got the same error at one point except it was referring to the compojure.core library.

Any suggestions on how to get this running are appreciated.

Comment: What version of leiningen are you running? I can't reproduce your problem with 2.5.0

Comment: Whatever leiningen is embedded in ccw 0.27.1. I'm trying to dig it up and it looks like 2.3.4 But I'm not totally sure. I've been debating skipping eclipse and installing leiningen directly to do this but I'm not sure how that will work with the eclipse project.